# Intellij IDEA 14.1.2 refuses to save file

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a line of code in a class that reads:

```
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

I changed it to `g.setColor(Color.WHITE);` but Intellij saves it as `g.setColor(Color.BLACK);`.

I have tried invalidating the cache in Intellij and restarting, and that has not fixed the problem.

I tried closing Intellij and editing the file in Notepad++. When I opened Intellij, it was still the old code, and Notepad++ told me that another program had modified the document. When I say yes to reload the document, it changes back to the old code.

Comment: No, both programs have permission to write to it. Both Intellij and Notepad++ write to it, but Intellij just writes the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sound like a bug to me, **kill any intelliJ instances and reopen it again to see if it solve the issue**, if not, close intelliJ again and try to edit it with notepad++, if it tell you the same things "that another program had modified the document" that mean there is a process with that file open that keep writing to it.

**Multiple Processes writing to the same file resolution:**
*(Also for file already opened by another program issue)*

You can use **Resources Monitor** of the Task Manager -> Performance tab and check for any associated handles with that file name you could use **Process Monitor** as well to achieve the same result: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx and kill the process that keep writing to it.

Dany

Comment: Restarting my computer, which would essentially do what Dany suggested, fixed the problem.